# Привести в верхний регистр

Tags: javascript

Существует некая строка, предположим "RqaEzty", которую требуется вывести в таком формате: "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
Код ниже выводит в таком: "R-qq-aaa-eeee-zzzzz-tttttt-yyyyyyy"
Вопрос, как привести к верхнему регистру нулевой индекс каждой первой буквы после "-"

```js
function accum(s) {
  let str = '';
  let l = s.length - 1;
  let spl = s.split('');

  for (let i = 0; i <= l; i++) {
    if (i != 0) str += '-';
    for (let k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
      str += spl[i];
      str = str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(accum("RqaEzty"));
```

Comment: * `console.log( "RqaEzty".split("").map( (e,i) => e.toUpperCase() + e.toLowerCase().repeat(i) ).join("-") );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function accum(s) {
  let str = '';
  let l = s.length - 1;
  let spl = s.split('');

  for (let i = 0; i <= l; i++) {
    if (i != 0) str += '-';
    str += spl[i].toUpperCase();
    for (let k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
      str += str[str.length - 1].toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(accum("RqaEzty"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
console.log(
  'RqaEzty'
  .replace(/./g, (s, f) => (f ? '-' : '') +
  s.toUpperCase() + s.toLowerCase().repeat(f))
)
```